# Angular which Dialog can display content of my different project components on full screen?

Tags: angular, dialog, popup, primeng

which Dialog (Pop Up) in Angular can display content of my different project components on full screen and how? I want to be able to open my content as pop up on the starting page.

When I look on the PrimeNG Dialog it seems just to work for service.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can add any component into `p-dialog`.
You can use `maximize()` method of dialog when opening your dialog.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-demo-hximkj)  is an example for content and maximized dialog in StackBlitz.

Comment: This is a good example. I still have a question to the routing, as I dont know how to deal with my red underlined code.

I want to put the dialog in a component I created (start.component.ts). I import the import 
{ PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';
import { Dialog } from 'primeng/dialog';

and get red underlining:

"Cannot find module 'primeng/dialog' or its corresponding type declarations"

In my app module I imported:
import { DialogModule } from 'primeng/dialog'; ----red underlined too
imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule, DialogModule],

Whats wrong?

Comment: Try to `npm i primeng`. If you vote my answer and select it as answer to your question, I will be appreciated. Have a nice day.